# IIS Application Pool not starting for SQL Server Master Data Services Website

Tags: iis-8, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

I have recently installed SQL Server Master Data Services, and as part of the set up, it creates a website through IIS. For this it requires a user name and password for the application pool, which I have given it:

[image]

I happen to have system administration rights on the server, so my own details should work.

When the setup is finished, it opens the web page, but I get Service Unavailable:

[image]

I searched for an answer and discovered there was a problem where the IIS application pool for Master Data Services won't start:

[image]

I can click start all I like - it doesn't start. I have tried changing the identity over to ApplicationPoolIdentity, but I can't add ApplicationPoolIdentity to the MDS configuration in the first picture. So I'm stuck.

The Windows Event Log says, "Application pool MDS Application Pool has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) did not create a worker process to serve the application pool because the application pool identity is invalid."

[image]

I'm confident this is a permissions issue somewhere, but I don't know what to do. As I say, my user has system admin permissions, so I don't know what the issue is.

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you checked the windows event log for errors?

Comment: Yes, it says, "Application pool MDS Application Pool has been disabled. Windows Process Activation Service (WAS) did not create a worker process to serve the application pool because the application pool identity is invalid." - in other words, its the application pool identity. But I don't know what to do now.

Comment: There is [a lot](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Windows+Process+Activation+Service+(WAS)+did+not+create+a+worker+process+to+serve+the+application+pool+because+the+application+pool+identity+is+invalid&oq=Windows+Process+Activation+Service+(WAS)+did+not+create+a+worker+process+to+serve+the+application+pool+because+the+application+pool+identity+is+invalid&aqs=chrome..69i57.208j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of material online already in relation to this error message.

Comment: There seem to be a few possible causes, which it isn't possible for us to determine solely from the error message itself. Have you looked into any of this yet?

Comment: I've followed your google link. And I've tried a couple of the solutions so far, but nothing so far has worked.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Did you check "Default Windows user rights assignments" on this machine? https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/981949/description-of-default-permissions-and-user-rights-for-iis-7-0-and-lat

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but I just got the same problem.
Admin Password was changed so I had to change it in the IIS Application Pool.

Comment: Here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc735276(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN